# Thread state conflict inside run method; Why thread state is not "RUNNING"

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing

I am doing some testing to understand the different thread states in a java, and got struck with a few queries.

Normally, when a thread is instantiated it is said to be in the `"NEW"` state and then when invoked the `start`() method on it, the operating system scheduler gets the control and is in `"RUNNABLE"` state and further when `run()` is invoked internally by `start()` it is said to be in running state.

```
Thread.currentThread().getState() // Returns the state of the thread
```

But observed when executed the below code, the thread state never gets displayed as `"RUNNING"` even when tested inside the `run` method.

Can anyone help me understand why does it behave like this ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        Thread t=new Thread(()->{
            System.out.println("Hi");
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getState());  //// STATE DISPLAYED AS "RUNNABLE" AGAIN
        });
        System.out.println(t.getState());  // STATE DISPLAYED AS "NEW"
        t.start();
        System.out.println(t.getState());  // STATE DISPLAYED AS "RUNNABLE"
}
```

lambda expression is used to implement the `run()` method where we are testing the state of the thread which again displays as "RUNNABLE" instead of "RUNNING"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the state `RUNNING` does not exist. If you look at the definition of the `getState` method you see the following:

```
public State getState() {
    // get current thread state
    return jdk.internal.misc.VM.toThreadState(threadStatus);
}
```

and if you analyze what `State` is, you can see that it is the following ENUM:

```
   public enum State {
        /**
         * Thread state for a thread which has not yet started.
         */
        NEW,

        /**
         * Thread state for a runnable thread.  A thread in the runnable
         * state is executing in the Java virtual machine but it may
         * be waiting for other resources from the operating system
         * such as processor.
         */
        RUNNABLE,

        /**
         * Thread state for a thread blocked waiting for a monitor lock.
         * A thread in the blocked state is waiting for a monitor lock
         * to enter a synchronized block/method or
         * reenter a synchronized block/method after calling
         * {@link Object#wait() Object.wait}.
         */
        BLOCKED,

        /**
         * Thread state for a waiting thread.
         * A thread is in the waiting state due to calling one of the
         * following methods:
         * <ul>
         *   <li>{@link Object#wait() Object.wait} with no timeout</li>
         *   <li>{@link #join() Thread.join} with no timeout</li>
         *   <li>{@link LockSupport#park() LockSupport.park}</li>
         * </ul>
         *
         * <p>A thread in the waiting state is waiting for another thread to
         * perform a particular action.
         *
         * For example, a thread that has called {@code Object.wait()}
         * on an object is waiting for another thread to call
         * {@code Object.notify()} or {@code Object.notifyAll()} on
         * that object. A thread that has called {@code Thread.join()}
         * is waiting for a specified thread to terminate.
         */
        WAITING,

        /**
         * Thread state for a waiting thread with a specified waiting time.
         * A thread is in the timed waiting state due to calling one of
         * the following methods with a specified positive waiting time:
         * <ul>
         *   <li>{@link #sleep Thread.sleep}</li>
         *   <li>{@link Object#wait(long) Object.wait} with timeout</li>
         *   <li>{@link #join(long) Thread.join} with timeout</li>
         *   <li>{@link LockSupport#parkNanos LockSupport.parkNanos}</li>
         *   <li>{@link LockSupport#parkUntil LockSupport.parkUntil}</li>
         * </ul>
         */
        TIMED_WAITING,

        /**
         * Thread state for a terminated thread.
         * The thread has completed execution.
         */
        TERMINATED;
    }
```

Or from API [Thread.State](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html):

> public static enum Thread.State extends Enum<Thread.State> A thread
> state. A thread can be in one of the following states:

> **NEW** A thread that has not yet started is in this state.
>
> **RUNNABLE** A thread executing in the Java virtual machine is in this state.

> **BLOCKED** A thread that is blocked waiting for a monitor lock is in this state.

> **WAITING** A thread that is waiting indefinitely for another thread to perform a particular action is in this state.

> **TIMED_WAITING** A thread that is waiting for another thread to perform an action for up to a specified waiting time is in this state.

> **TERMINATED** A thread that has exited is in this state. A thread can be in only one state at a given point in
> time. These states are virtual machine states which do not reflect any
> operating system thread states.

Comment: Thank you ,i have gone through some online tutorials like https://www.javatpoint.com/life-cycle-of-a-thread which state there is a "RUNNING" state. As per my understanding "RUNNABLE" is the control of the operating system scheduler, if this understanding is wrong, can we say that "RUNNABLE" is the state where operating system's scheduler gains control and then starts executing it ? as there is no separate "RUNNING"  state.

Comment: @Rakesh From the java doc you get actually a good answer, "Thread state for a runnable thread.  A thread in the runnable state is executing in the Java virtual machine but it may be waiting for other resources from the operating system such as processor."

Comment: @Rakesh, Think of it this way, "RUNNABLE" means that there is no reason _that the Java Runtime Environment knows of_ why the thread can not run. But there may be reasons that the OS knows of that the JRE does not (e.g., all of the CPUs currently are allocated to other threads.)